# Angular 2 rc1 component initialization

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am experimenting with `Angular 2 rc1` and have a very simple component.
As displayed it fails:

```
import { Component, OnInit }    from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response }       from '@angular/http';
import { Observable }           from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Movie }                from "./movie";
import { MovieService }         from "./movieService";

import "rxjs/add/operator/map";

@Component
({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <p>{{mov.Rating}}</p>
        <ul>
          <li *ngFor="let movie of movies" >
            {{movie.Title}} - {{movie.Rating}}
          </li>
        </ul>
        `,
    providers: [MovieService]
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit
{
    public name: string;
    public mov: Movie;// = { Title: "bla", Rating: 3 };
    public movies: Movie[];

    constructor(private movieService: MovieService) {}

    public ngOnInit()
    {
        this.movieService.getMovies()
            .subscribe(movies =>
            {
                this.movies = movies;
                this.mov = this.movies[1];
            });
    }
}
```

If I do initialize the `mov` variable (and no other change) it will work just fine.

When it fails, the browser (chrome, firefox or IE) throws an exception ("TypeError: Cannot read property 'Rating' of undefined") and ends execution.
`MovieService` does an actual API call which takes a few milliseconds and during that time `mov` is indeed undefined.
In Angular1 that was not a problem; it would simply display nothing.

I tried making the `movieService` call in the `constructor` but that made no difference.

Is that intended behavior, a bug or am I missing something and there is a way to prevent it (except initialization of the `mov` variable)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is intended behavior. As you already noted the `mov` variable is indeed undefined when the component is initialized. Therefore Angular can't read the `Rating` property of `mov`. Only when the API call returns, the `mov` variable is filled.

You could indeed initialize the variable in the constructor. Another, perhaps cleaner way is to use the Elvis operator in your template:

```
 <p>{{mov?.Rating}}</p>
```

The Elvis operator guards against null (/uninitialized) values.